# Excel VBA - Referencing Range using Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to dynamically add `validation` (using DataValidation:List) to ranges in a worksheet.  I recorded a macro that produced the following code:

```
With Worksheets("Clusters").Range("C2:C100").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Managers"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

This was working fine for the static range C2:C100, but the column may not be always be C.  I have a variable cMANFCM that contains the column number.  I tried to edit the code to use this:

```
With Worksheets("Clusters").Range(Cells(2,cMANFCM), Cells(100, cMANFCM)).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Managers"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Why doesn't this work and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try `With Worksheets("Clusters").Range("A2:A100").Offset(, cMANFCM-1).Validation`

Comment: or `Worksheets("Clusters").Cells(2,cMANFCM).Resize(100,1)`

Comment: `Cells()` without a qualifying worksheet will always refer to the ActiveSheet, so instead of using (e.g.) `sht.Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(100,1))` you should use `sht.Range(sht.Cells(1,1), sht.Cells(100,1))`

Comment: I believe Tim's comment is where your issue lies

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Tim was right, the problem is that I wasn't referring to the sheet.  sht.cells(....) worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works on mine - I've added a line to delete *all* existing validation and it does create new validation without throwing an error:

Lots of the validation arguments can probably be ignored...and you've got a choice of how to reference the sheet/range when other sheets are active:

```
Option Explicit
Sub control()
    'Call changeValidation(4)
    'Call changeValidationPAlbert(5)
    Call changeValidationTWilliams(6)
End Sub

Sub changeValidation(cMANFCM As Integer)

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Clusters")
    .Cells.Validation.Delete
    .Range(.Cells(2, cMANFCM), .Cells(100, cMANFCM)).Validation.Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, _
            Formula1:="=managers"
End With

End Sub
Sub changeValidationAlbert(cMANFCM As Integer)

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Clusters")
    .Cells.Validation.Delete
    .Range("A2:A100").Offset(, cMANFCM - 1).Validation.Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, _
            Formula1:="=managers"
End With

End Sub
Sub changeValidationTWilliams(cMANFCM As Integer)

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Clusters")
    .Cells.Validation.Delete
    .Cells(2, cMANFCM).Resize(100, 1).Validation.Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, _
            Formula1:="=managers"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this will error if "Clusters"is not the active sheet: see my comment above.

Comment: - correct Tim: I've now amended and tested and it seems to work when other sheets are activated. I didn't realize the OPer wanted this functionality (but probably why the got the error in the first place) ...although it's good practice and defensive coding to include it